# Combine results into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to clean this up and only have one instance instead of 10.

This certain entry is connected to each of the individual data pieces within the `CASE` statements (10 of the 12 listed).

Seeing if anyone has any ideas (other than joining the CTE over and over, i.e.

```
LEFT JOIN sessions_CTE scte1 on scte1.person_id = p.person_id and 
scte1.session_id = '229856'
LEFT JOIN sessions_CTE scte2 on scte2.person_id = p.person_id and scte2.session_id = '229846'
LEFT JOIN sessions_CTE scte3 on scte3.person_id = p.person_id and scte3.session_id = '229798'...
```

That works fine, it just is huge and sketchy on the DB)

Here is my query, thanks for any ideas you guys might have:

```
WITH sessions_CTE AS
(
        select
            a.person_id,
            s.session_id,
            s.abbreviation,
            s.title,
            st.sessionTime_id,
            d.abbreviation as day,
            sl.minutes length,
            r.name room
          from
            attendeesregistered a
            inner join sessiontimes st on a.sessiontime_id = 
st.sessiontime_id
            inner join sessions s on st.session_id = s.session_id
            inner join slots on st.slot_id = slots.slot_id
            inner join days d on slots.day_id = d.day_id
            inner join rooms r on slots.room_id = r.room_id
            inner join slottimes on slots.slottime = 
slottimes.slottime_id
            inner join ses_length sl on slottimes.length = 
sl.ses_length_id
WHERE a.event = '23533'
--and ROWNUM <= 10
)

SELECT  DISTINCT p.person_id,
    p.email "Email",
    p.firstname "First Name",
    p.lastname "Last Name",
    p.jobTitle "Job Title",
    p.companyname "Company Name",
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229744' THEN 'Registered'
       -- ELSE ''
    END as ExecutiveChannelPartnerMeeting,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229753' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as ChickenParm,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229761' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as Pesto,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229764' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as mcyds,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229770' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as bigmac,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229840' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as mtndew,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229841' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as sprite,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229852' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as corndogs,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229853' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as burritto,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229856' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as mickeymouse,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229842' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as mario,
    CASE
        WHEN scte.session_id = '229847' THEN 'Registered'
        ELSE ''
    END as link
    --scte.session_id,
    --scte.title
FROM people p
RIGHT JOIN sessions_CTE scte on scte.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE p.event = '23533'
AND p.person_id = 2388207
--AND ROWNUM <= 25
--GROUP BY p.person_id
```

Current output:

```
ID         |  Exec.   |Chicken Parm |  Pesto    | ......
----------- ---------- ------------- ----------- ------------
2388207    | Registered| (NULL)     | (NULL)    | ........
----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ------------
2388207    | (NULL)    |  (NULL)    | Reistered | ........
----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ------------
2388207    | (NULL)    |  Registered|  (NULL)   | ........
----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ------------
```

Desired Output

```
ID         |  Exec.    |Chicken Parm |  Pesto    | ......
--------------------------------------------------------------
2388207    |Registered | Registered  | Registered| ........
----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ------------
```

Comment: Can you give some sample output vs desired output to give some understanding. As of now, I'm wondering why you can't use a when scte.session_id in (id1,id2,id3). I normally work in t-sql vs oracle but that is pretty standard

Comment: Can you do case when scte.sessionid in (,) else ‘’

Comment: Sorry, I added output(s) to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by, and then use MAX for the CASE WHEN's

```
WITH sessions_CTE AS
(
...
)
SELECT
p.person_id,
p.email AS "Email",
p.firstname AS "First Name",
p.lastname AS "Last Name",
p.jobTitle AS "Job Title",
p.companyname AS "Company Name",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229744' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "ExecutiveChannelPartnerMeeting",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229753' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "ChickenParm",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229761' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "Pesto",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229764' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "mcyds",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229770' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "bigmac",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229840' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "mtndew",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229841' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "sprite",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229852' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "corndogs",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229853' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "burritto",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229856' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "mickeymouse",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229842' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "mario",
MAX(CASE WHEN session_id = '229847' THEN 'Registered' END) AS "link"
FROM people p
RIGHT JOIN sessions_CTE scte on scte.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE p.event = '23533'
  AND p.person_id = 2388207
GROUP BY p.person_id, p.email, p.firstname, p.lastname, p.jobTitle, p.companyname;
```

Comment: @SpencerBertrand Thanks. Btw, just FYI, another way to do this is using [PIVOT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php) But I didn't use that method because with those long names it wouldn't really golfcode the SQL. And you'd have to hardcode those names twice.

Comment: that's another good piece to know. Thanks! And the first time I wrote the query I had to hardcode the names twice and there were two many lines of duplicated names in the query and I didn't feel like doing that again. ha ha